# .net application throw outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, out-of-memory, clr

I have two windows server 2003 has 8GB and 16GB RAM.

when run a test program on the servers, all of them throws OutOfMemory Exception, when the heap size of test program reached at 738Mb.

I have search that windows server will just using 60% of 2Gb User memory address, it might be 1.2Gb.

so,
1. which machine target decide the max memory?
2. why 8Gb and 16Gb server show the same performance?
3. Some document said 1.2Gb(about) depends on Private Bytes or Working Set or Virtual Bytes Or the heap size?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand all your questions, but I recommend you read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx).  Some key points:

> The amount of data storage reserved for a process is only limited by the amount of space that the operating system can get on the disk. (*)
>
> An “out of memory” error almost never happens because there’s not enough storage available; as we’ve seen, storage is disk space, and disks are huge these days. Rather, an “out of memory” error happens because the process is unable to find a large enough section of contiguous unused pages in its virtual address space to do the requested mapping.
>
> it should be clear why “out of memory” errors usually have nothing to do with how much physical memory you have, or how even how much storage is available. It’s almost always about the address space, which on 32 bit Windows is relatively small and easily fragmented.